# Marquee suggestions for HTML web page

Tags: html

i want to put a marquee on my web, i only now to methods to do that:

Html  >  tab
Flash > a simple actionscript

But, dont you know a better method to do that? with jquery maybe. Thanks for your recomendation.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [jQuery Marquee Demo](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html) page. Seem to work pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Although deprecated, the marquee tag is still widely supported by most browsers. I would advise against using any kind of marquee personally, but try the marquee HTML tag. http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_MARQUEE.html

The advantage of using the native marquee tag is that you'll get better performance than jQuery unless your page is going to have hundreds of them showing at once.